# JavaScript: Tracking Selection Change on Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, android, events, dom-events, textselection

I'm looking for a way to track the text selection on a web page. I need some code to be executed whenever there is a change in selection. I have successfully done this on all major desktop browsers, but the same does not seem to be working on Firefox for Android.

I tried three approaches (none of them worked!):

1. Tried catching the `"mouseup"` event and checking if there is a
   non-empty text selection. Problem is `"mouseup"` isn't getting
   triggered if a selection was made during the mousedown-move-up
   sequence!
2. Tried doing the same with the `"touchend"` event - Same result.
3. Tried catching the [`"selectionchange"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange) event. I saw that it isn’t
   triggered when the selection changes as it needs the config key
   `"dom.select_events.enabled"` to be set. This is `false` by default and I obviously can't ask my visitors to tweak browser settings :-)

Also, as expected, the first two events don't get triggered if the selection is extended or reduced by dragging the selection start/end markers.

The only solution I can think of now is a periodic poller (using setInterval) that checks if there is a text selection. This is definitely unclean and anti-performance.

Any alternatives and/or advice will be very  helpful.

Comment: where are you binding mouseup event, to body/document/html? try combination of them.

Comment: Just tested it on firefox mobile and indeed it doesn't trigger any event >.>

Comment: You can create a poller when a selection has started using the mouseup event and then remove the poller when there hasn't been a selection for X seconds. Can't think of anything else to solve this besides hoping that the selectionchange event becomes default soon :/

Comment: Yes, that's kind of what I'm doing now. I'm starting the poller on mousedown in fact, and clearing it when there isn't a selection change for 3 seconds. Feels very unclean but. The poller runs every 500ms which luckily doesn't seem to be affecting the performance as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1) Native Text Selection Events

Currently, polling seems to be the only work-around.
However, the `selectionchange` event [is currently experimentally implemented in Firefox for Android Nightly](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571294). It can be enabled by setting the `dom.select_events.enabled` flag to `true` (defaults to `false`).

**In Nightly builds, this flag already defaults to `true`**, so there is a chance you can use it normally in a couple of months.

## 2) Find events that work

**(UNTESTED!!)**

Even if `onselectstart` cannot be used productively in Firefox for Android yet, the only viable easy solution is polling.

To improve performance and reduce costs, **polling can be started on the window `blur` event**. Because whenever the user is making a selection, the focus should be set off the viewport **(untested though)**.

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    // start polling for text selections
});
```

When the **focus is given back**, **polling can be stopped**.

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function(){
    // stop polling
});
```

To **check if the browser actually supports text selection events**, you can use this function:

```
var browserSupportsTextSelectionEvents = function(){
    return !!('onselectstart' in document.body);
}
```

## 3) Hacking

A third idea is to disable text selection for mobile Firefox users via CSS (`-moz-user-select: none`), implement a custom text selection function based on touch start and end positions and pushing the native selection range back to the browser via `HTMLElement.setSelectionRange()`.

Comment: Yeah, polling seems to be the only way out for now, at least till `selectionchange` is adopted into the stable channel. Thanks anyway for your efficiency related inputs regarding when to start/stop the poller. Though I'm yet to test it, it does look like the way forward. Thanks.

Comment: I think the "Hacking" method (3) is the most promising. I can't try it because I have no Android + Firefox to test it, but with this solution no polling is needed. Just hook `window.getSelection()` after the `touchend` event. This event will be fired if user selection is disabled via CSS.